Using rvest to webscrap a website partially protected by a login
I want to scrap some data from a web page, but this page is partially protected with username/password.
And i would like to scrap data that is only available after i logged in. I found how to navigate once the login is cleared, so no problem for the after.
But the problem i encounter is that my page seems to not be found.
On the code below, the url is where i can enter my informations to log in. And when i use the html_session function or even the newest session function i get the error : "In session_set_response(x, resp) : Not Found (HTTP 404)."
(Code was found on a similar question asked on stackoverflow : Using rvest to scrape a website w/ a login page )
library(rvest)

#login
url <- "https://leghe.fantacalcio.it/login"
session <- html_session(url)

form <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          username = "notmyrealemail",
                          password = "notmyrealpassword")

submit_form(session, filled_form)

I also found a deprecated solution with the request_POST function, that allowed at the same time to enter the URL we want to navigate to after the login cleared. But i did not find any function similar since the deprecation of it.

Despite 404, content is actually served. Not sure if this is some kind configuration issue or something designed to confuse bots and automated tools.
Though it doesn't make much difference as the whole user interface (incl. login form) is rendered by javascript in your browser and html_session() would get virtually empty document (you can check view-source:https://leghe.fantacalcio.it/login in your browser).
You might have better luck with rvest::read_html_live() which will open that page though chromote / Chrome and allows you to interact with the live session.
library(rvest)

url_ <- "https://leghe.fantacalcio.it/login"
session <- read_html_live(url)

# fill form, click on LOGIN button
session$type("input[formcontrolname='username']", "notmyrealemail")
session$type("input[formcontrolname='password']", "notmyrealpassword")
session$click("button")

# check current view
session$view()

# continue with the session 
session |> 
  html_elements("title")


